# How to use random numbers when running redis-benchmark?

Tags: redis

I used this but it doesn't work:

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000000 zadd ss ele:rand:000000000000 ele:rand:000000000000
```

After this,

```
zcard ss
```

still returns 0 reuslt.

Why?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with this command line.

- The second parameter of the zadd command must be a score (i.e. a number), not a key name. You cannot use ele:rand:000000000000 to represent a score. In your example, all the commands fail, that's why you have nothing in the zset in the end.
- You are supposed to use the -r option to set the range for the random values of the keys

Example:

```
$ redis-benchmark -r 10000 -n 1000000 zadd ss 0 ele:rand:000000000000
$ redis-cli zcard ss
(integer) 10000
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to generate random score, in redis-benchmark command line?

Comment: No, because the :rand: tag is kept in the resulting string.

Comment: @okwap, use  `redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -r 1000000 -q -P 32 zadd zset __rand_int__ __rand_int__` instead

Comment: just notice you won't end up having 1M elements in the set because rand_int may generate elements that are already in the set